# Добавить номер заказа в БД

Tags: php

Нужен совет спецов, есть таблица с зарегистрированными пользователями, таблица с заказами, дак вот, зарегеный пользователь накидывает n-количество товаров в корзину, которые записываются в таблицу БД, получается, нужно присвоить этим заказам один номер и связать с таблицей пользователей т.е. получить последний номер товара из таблици заказов и связать с таблицей пользователей? Но тогда возможен вариант одновременного добавление товаров несколькими пользователями, что может повлиять на неправильное создание номера заказа.

Comment: Не совсем понял, в чём проблема

Comment: Ну так присвойте продуктам в корзине ид пользователя их добавившего.

Comment: А номер как формировать?

Comment: Если одновременно несколько пользователей накидали товаров то при получении последнего номера заказа может возникнуть проблема, не факт, что он будет именно последним.

Comment: Зачем получать последний номер заказа?

Answer (score 2):

Номер заказа не присваивается, когда пользователь добавляет товар.
Номер заказа формируется, когда пользователь оформляет заказ.
К товарам номер заказа вообще ни имеет никакого отношения.
Номер заказа должен формироваться с помощью autoincrement, и это будет гарантировать отсутствие коллизий.

Comment: С помощью autoincrement формируется id товара, если добавили 10 товаров то у каждого товара будет свой уникальный id, а вот заказ это один, например 21 т.е. в БД каждый заказа запишется под уникальным id, а вот в колонке number будет один номер.